# How to develop a Jquery plugin to find the first child that match with a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make a Jquery plugin (`findFirst()`) to find the first child with a given characteristics (something in the middle of the `find()` and `children()` functions. For instance, given this markup:

```
<div id="start">
    <div>
        <span>Hello world</span>
        <ul class="valid-result"> ... </ul>
        <ul class="valid-result">
            <li>
                <ul class="not-a-result"> ... </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <ul class="valid-result"> ... </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you ask for `$("#start").findFirst('ul')` it should return all *ul* lists that I have tagged with the *valid-result* class, but not the *ul* with class *not-a-result*. It is, this function has to find the first elements that matches with a given selector, but not the inner elements that match this selector.

This is the first time I try to code a Jquery function, and what I've already read doesn't helps me too much with this. The function I have developed is this:

```
jQuery.fn.findFirst = function (sel) {
    return this.map(function() {
        return $(this).children().map(function() {
            if ($(this).is(sel)) {
                return $(this);
            } else {
                return $(this).findFirst(sel);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It works in the sense it tries to return the expected result, but the format it returns the result is very rare for me. I suppose the problem is something I don't understand about Jquery. Here you have [the JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2Lfr/1/) where I'm testing.

**EDIT**

The expected result after `$("#start").findFirst('ul')` is **a set** with all UL that have the class 'valid-result' BUT it's not possible to use this class because it doesn't exist in a real case (it's just to try to explain the result).

This is not equivalent to first(), because first returns only one element!

Comment: If you are doing this as an exercise in how to learn to write a plug-in, that is OK, but you should make that note specifically, otherwise, you are really duplicating existing functionaltiy.

Comment: I believe, I have explained very bad.. Editing...

Comment: I put some more example in as an answer - explore these to gain an understanding of the selector options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var selector='ul';

var $results= $('#start '+selector).not( selector +' '+selector);
```

The `not()` method will exclude elements that match selector but are also descendents of the same selector

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to build a plugin. use jQuery inbuilt [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and as suggested by Mark, you can also use first selector [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
$("#yourselector ul").first();
```

Here is the usages in your case

```
$("#start").find("ul").first().css("background", "red");
   //For Short $("#start ul").first()
```

To use class filter, use the attribute selector

```
$("#start").find("ul[class=valid-result]").first().css("background", "red");
   //For Short $("#start ul[class=valid-result]").first()
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/f3m5y/)

---

**Update**

If you want to highlight only the outer ul's with class `valid-result` then `first()` is not needed at all

```
$("#start ul[class=valid-result]").css("background", "red");
```

But, since the inner ul will also share the background on my example, you might have to set different background for inner `ul`'s. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/f3m5y/1/)

---

**Update 2**

If you want to select the first level of the `<ul>` then

```
$("#start div").chilrent("ul"); //this will return the first level of ul inside the div
```

Comment: or `$('selector:first')` which gives similar result but your syntax is often faster and more understandable.

Comment: As far as I know, first() returns the FIRST element in a set. It couldn't be filtered by a selector and it returns **only one** matching. I need all the outer elements that match the given selector.

Comment: @Ivan, Yeah, It was missing in the first. I was trying to make it more understandable

Comment: Don't trust in "valid-result" !!! It is only in the sample to explain it easier! :)

Comment: The demo only changes the background for the first list item. The idea is that all **outer** ULs should be higlighted

Comment: @Ivan, I dont think, `first()` has no use then. Updated that too

Comment: Sorry @Startx, you cannot trust in 'valid-result' class because it won't exist in a real case. See edit, please.

Comment: @Ivan, then what is the real case?

Comment: Real case is as explained. Sorry, maybe my bad english makes me not to explain well... But I need a plugin that given this input (findFirst("ul")) over a selector ($("#first")) chooses the UL items that are NOT contained by any other UL.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $('#selector:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

selectors that all give the result for your example:

<strike>$('#start>*>ul')
    $('#start').children().find('>ul')
    $('#start').children('div').find('span').siblings('ul')</strike>

```
$('#start').children().find('span').siblings('ul')
$('#start').find('span').siblings('ul')
```

edit: anther example:

```
$('#start>div>span').siblings('ul')
$('#start').find('div').find('span').siblings('ul')
$('#start>div>span').siblings('ul')
```

WOOPS, SCRATCH ALL THOSE, I missed that last inner UL in the div...

SO: this (I tested it out) DOES get those child ul of the div but not inside the li

```
 $('#start div').find('>ul')
 $('#start div>ul')
```

What this says is find a UL that is a direct decendant of a DIV